# Orthogonal projections and being trace class

Tags: functional-analysis, trace

On some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, I have two orthogonal projections $P,Q:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. In fact, $Q=UPU^*$ for some unitary $U$ (Note that $Q$ is indeed another orthogonal projection).

I have shown that the following operator
\begin{align}
A:=P-PQP=P-PUPU^*P\,,
\end{align}
is trace-class. However, in this particular setting, I am very interested in whether or not *this* operator is trace-class,
\begin{align}
B:=P-Q = P-UPU^*\,.
\end{align}
Notice how $A = PBP$. It might not be true at all that $B$ is trace-class, but I was wondering if there are any results out there about trace-class products of operators that I can exploit to investigate whether or not $B$ is trace-class. Intuitively, I think the trace-class property of $A$ must have something to do with $B$, because in my case the projection $P$ is the projection of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ onto $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R})$, that is, it restricts functions to the upper half-plane (I defined this projection $P$ by means of multiplication operators). I have showed that an orthogonal projection is only trace-class if the dimension of its range is finite, and this really doesn't seem to be the case for $P$, so my guts are telling me that it must have something to do with $B$.

Any links to material are appreciated, or arguments for either cases. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem problem, you may consider accepting it. Otherwise, you can let me know how I can further clarify any further concerns.

Comment: I will return to it shortly! I am currently brewing on something myself which I believe might solve my particular case. Can two different answers be accepted?

Comment: No only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathcal{H}= \mathcal{K}\oplus \mathcal{K}$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is an arbitrary Hilbert space and let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the first component and $Q$ on the second component. Let $U: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ be the unitary that switches components. Then
$$Q = UPU^* = UPU$$
Note further that $PQ = QP = 0$. Thus $B= P-Q$ is also a projection. However, if $\mathcal{K}$ has infinite-dimension, then $B$ does not have finite-dimensional range and thus $B$ is not trace-class by the observation you have made.

Thus, in general, $B$ not not be trace-class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply QuantumSpace, it makes perfectly good sense. I am getting started on index theory, specifically for a pair of projections, and a result says that we can give a meaningful definition of Ind(P,Q) if (P-Q)^(2n+1) is trace class for some n, so it definitely should not always be the case. However, I should have emphasized that what I am really looking for is whether we can say that either S or O are trace-class if the product of the two, SO, is trace-class, which is kind of my situation here (with SOS).

Comment: @mk_math. With the same notation as in my answer: $PQ=0$ is trace-class yet $P,Q$ are not trace-class so this answers the question in your comment.

Comment: Of course, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @mk_math Glad to help!